# How to use Kotlinx DateTime with Kotlin MongoDB Driver

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, server, ktor

So KMongo for Kotlin is deprecated because of the new official driver (which has been around since 2016)

I'm trying to insert data to the database using an instance of data class that has `Instant` and `LocalDateTime` in it

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class User(
    val createdAt: Instant,
    val updatedAt: Instant,
)
```

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for CodecCacheKey{clazz=class kotlinx.datetime.Instant, types=null}.
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.lambda$get$0(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:80)
    at org.bson.internal.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:68)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.getCodec(DataClassCodec.kt:226)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.getCodec(DataClassCodec.kt:199)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.create$bson_kotlin(DataClassCodec.kt:148)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodecProvider.get(DataClassCodecProvider.kt:28)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider.get(KotlinCodecProvider.java:83)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:70)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.OverridableUuidRepresentationCodecProvider.get(OverridableUuidRepresentationCodecProvider.java:47)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.lambda$get$0(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:80)
    at org.bson.internal.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:68)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.getCodec(DataClassCodec.kt:226)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.getCodec(DataClassCodec.kt:199)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodec$Companion.create$bson_kotlin(DataClassCodec.kt:148)
    at org.bson.codecs.kotlin.DataClassCodecProvider.get(DataClassCodecProvider.kt:28)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at com.mongodb.KotlinCodecProvider.get(KotlinCodecProvider.java:83)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:70)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.OverridableUuidRepresentationCodecProvider.get(OverridableUuidRepresentationCodecProvider.java:47)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.getFromCodecProvider(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:95)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.lambda$get$0(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:80)
    at org.bson.internal.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.getCodec(Operations.java:746)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.bulkWrite(Operations.java:466)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.Operations.insertOne(Operations.java:392)
    at com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncOperations.insertOne(AsyncOperations.java:202)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$insertOne$6(MongoOperationPublisher.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.createWriteOperationMono(MongoOperationPublisher.java:446)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.createSingleWriteRequestMono(MongoOperationPublisher.java:454)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.insertOne(MongoOperationPublisher.java:261)
    at com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoCollectionImpl.insertOne(MongoCollectionImpl.java:367)
    at com.mongodb.kotlin.client.coroutine.MongoCollection.insertOne(MongoCollection.kt:627)
    at com.mongodb.kotlin.client.coroutine.MongoCollection.insertOne$default(MongoCollection.kt:626)
```

I don't know how to create a codec for Kotlinx DateTime types and I can't find one, so can anyone tell me how to do it? thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround:

```kotlin
class InstantCodec : Codec<Instant> {
    override fun encode(writer: BsonWriter, value: Instant, encoderContext: EncoderContext) {
        writer.writeDateTime(value.toEpochMilliseconds())
    }

    override fun decode(reader: BsonReader, decoderContext: DecoderContext): Instant {
        return Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(reader.readDateTime())
    }

    override fun getEncoderClass(): Class<Instant> {
        return Instant::class.java
    }
}
```

You also need to register it using

```kotlin
 .withCodecRegistry(
                CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                    CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(InstantCodec()),
                    MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry()
                ),
            )
```

Read more in the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/fundamentals/data-formats/codecs/)

But that's still not an answer, in my opinion, the official docs say the codecs and bson work with Kotlinx serialization in an efficient way

**Edit**:

That's the [answer](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-5296) from the MongoDB Team

First, you need the following [dependencies](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/fundamentals/data-formats/serialization/)

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-core:1.5.1")
implementation("org.mongodb:bson-kotlinx:5.0.0")
```

You will also need a custom KSerializer

```kotlin
object InstantAsBsonDateTime : KSerializer<Instant> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("InstantAsBsonDateTime", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Instant) {
        when (encoder) {
            is BsonEncoder -> encoder.encodeBsonValue(BsonDateTime(value.toEpochMilliseconds()))
            else -> throw SerializationException("Instant is not supported by ${encoder::class}")
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Instant {
        return when (decoder) {
            is BsonDecoder -> Instant.fromEpochMilliseconds(decoder.decodeBsonValue().asDateTime().value)
            else -> throw SerializationException("Instant is not supported by ${decoder::class}")
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in your data class

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class Foo(val name: String,
               @Serializable(with = InstantAsBsonDateTime::class)
               val createdAt: Instant)
```